# Explorer not updating after creating directories with SQL Server 2012 FileTable

Tags: sql-server, filestream, explorer, sql-server-2012, filetable

I am trying to create directories in a SQL Server FileTable via a stored procedure where I call the following code:

```
INSERT INTO tblMyFiles (name, is_directory, is_archive) 
VALUES ('foldername', 1, 0);
```

After calling this code I can see the row sitting in the File Table if I select the rows in SQL Server Management Studio but if I explore to the File Table directory via Windows Explorer I can not see the newly created directory. If I refresh Windows Explorer then the directory still does not show up. If I create a file in the File Table directory in Explorer then it seems to wake Explorer up and then all my directories that were created via the stored procedure appear.

I do not run into this problem when running this on the same SQL box and for a different database and I have compared all the properties and they appear identical but I must be missing something and don't know what? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an Explorer issue, not a SQL Server one.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this same issue - there seems to be a problem with Explorer caching the network share directory structure indefinitely. I also noticed that it won't refresh until I create a file and then delete it - then magically the cache refreshes. Deleting a file must force a directory cache refresh.

This cache problem seems to be **SMB** related - I tried both SMB 2 (*Windows 7*) and SMB 3 (*Windows 8*) and experienced this same issue. SQL 2012 [FileTables are supposed to support SMB 3](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/SQL11UPD03-REC-05).

After [following this TechNet forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/947489ae-dc86-45f0-ad5e-463a62e1d59f), [**disabling the SMB directory cache**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) makes it refresh every time (*verified on Win7 and Win8*). I'm guessing it could be SQL Server not sending the proper SMB messages or a bug in the SMB client stack. Either way - Microsoft needs to address it since they manage both the client and server design.

#### Disabling the SMB Directory Cache

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters]
> "DirectoryCacheLifetime"=dword:00000000